# Can text be resizable using jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can html text in p tag is resizable using jquery-ui or without p tag in a div tag is resizable? I have done resizing the image using jquery ui from following example but text is not getting resized http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use resize event handler. The trick is how to calculate new font size. Check this solution as a variant:

Html:

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
    <div id="content">Quis non magna sagittis, et cras tortor nunc? Enim, lectus et quis penatibus enim augue eros, dis sit sit urna cras placerat sociis porta</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var initDiagonal;
var initFontSize;

$(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable({
        alsoResize: '#content',
        create: function(event, ui) {
            initDiagonal = getContentDiagonal();
            initFontSize = parseInt($("#content").css("font-size"));
        },
        resize: function(e, ui) {
            var newDiagonal = getContentDiagonal();
            var ratio = newDiagonal / initDiagonal;

            $("#content").css("font-size", initFontSize + ratio * 3);
        }
    });
});

function getContentDiagonal() {
    var contentWidth = $("#content").width();
    var contentHeight = $("#content").height();
    return contentWidth * contentWidth + contentHeight * contentHeight;
}
```

You may look this solution at jsFiddle: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/eMXTQ/)

Comment: Thanks very much. Thanks very much for help i was really looking for that thanks very much.

Comment: Good stuff. I didn't quite understand the question!

Comment: Why do you multiply by 3? Sorry I don't get it where does it come from?

Answer (score 2):

Text sizing has nothing to do with jQuery specifically. You can tie a CSS property to a slider, however.

```
$('#slideBar').slider({
    startValue: 12,
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 100,
    stop: function(e, ui) { 
        $("#text").css({fontSize: ui.value + 8});

    }
});
```