# Resizing font size when resizing a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a web application which allow you to add dynamics `div`s which are resizable and draggable by jQuery into a `div` container with a black background.

Here is the code of this app:

```css
.centrer {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    height : 768px;
    width : 432px;
    background-color : #000000;
}

.menu {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    float:left;
    text-align : center;
}

h3, li, ul{
    text-align : left;
}

.encadrer {
    border: 1px solid white;
    height : 120px;
    position:absolute !important;
}

.centrerTitre{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color : white;
    margin : auto;
    text-align : center;
    padding-top : 7px;
}

.centrerPara{
    font-size: 16;
    color : white;
    margin : auto;
    text-align : center;
    padding-left : 7px;
    padding-right : 7px;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}

.encadrer:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

/*----- Resizable ------*/
.ui-resizable { position: relative;}
.ui-resizable-handle { position: absolute;font-size: 0.1px;z-index: 99999; display: block;}
.ui-resizable-disabled .ui-resizable-handle, .ui-resizable-autohide .ui-resizable-handle { display: none; }
.ui-resizable-n { cursor: n-resize; height: 7px; width: 100%; top: -5px; left: 0px; }
.ui-resizable-s { cursor: s-resize; height: 7px; width: 100%; bottom: -5px; left: 0px; }
.ui-resizable-e { cursor: e-resize; width: 7px; right: -5px; top: 0px; height: 100%; }
.ui-resizable-w { cursor: w-resize; width: 7px; left: -5px; top: 0px; height: 100%; }
.ui-resizable-nw { cursor: nw-resize; height: 7px; width: 7px; top: -5px; left: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-se { cursor: se-resize; height: 7px; width: 7px; right: -5px; bottom: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-ne { cursor: ne-resize; height: 7px; width: 7px; top: -5px; right: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-sw { cursor: sw-resize; height: 7px; width: 7px; left: -5px; bottom: -5px; }
/*----------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Affichage</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <body>
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
            <h3>Taille de l'écran</h3>

            <select id='selector'>
                <option value="1920x1080">1920x1080</option>
            </select>
            </br></br>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" id="portrait" name="orientation" value="portrait" checked="checked">Portrait</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" id="paysage" name="orientation" value="paysage">Paysage</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </br>
            <h3>Ajouter des éléments</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="ajoutImage" href="#" onclick="return false;">Image</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="bg"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
            bg.className = "centrer";

            var ajoutImg = document.getElementById('ajoutImage');

            var initDiagonal;
            var initFontSize;

            var rad = document.getElementsByName('orientation');

            for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
                rad[i].onclick = tailleEcran;
            }

            document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener("change", tailleEcran, false);

            ajoutImg.onclick = function() {

                //var name = prompt("Texte de l'image :");

                var container = document.createElement("div");
                container.className = 'encadrer';
                var inner = document.createElement("div");
                inner.className = 'inner';
                var titre = document.createElement("p");
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                titre.textContent = "Titre";
                titre.className = 'centrerTitre';
                inner.appendChild(titre);
                para.textContent = prompt("Texte de l'image :");;
                para.className = 'centrerPara';
                inner.appendChild(para);
                container.appendChild(inner);

                //var container = $('<div class="encadrer"><div class="inner"><p class="centrerTitre">Titre</p><p class="centrerPara">' + name + '</p></div></div>');
                bg.appendChild(container);

                $(container)
                .draggable({containment:"parent"})
                .resizable({
                    containment:"parent",
                    handles: "all"
                });
            };

            function tailleEcran() {
                switch(document.getElementById("selector").value){
                    case '1920x1080' :
                        if(document.getElementById("portrait").checked == true){
                            bg.style.height = '768px';
                            bg.style.width = '432px';
                        }else{
                            bg.style.height = '432px';
                            bg.style.width = '768px';
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make the font size of the content of the dynamic `div` resizing when you resize the `div`, as you can see at this post:

[Can text be resizable using jquery-ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582289/can-text-be-resizable-using-jquery-ui)

I put all the nodes into variables, but I failed to add this function to my app.

Someone know how I can do that?

Thanks for your attention,

Regards,

Maxime OZENNE.

Comment: I wrote a jquery plugin to do this a long time ago, check it out - https://github.com/ozzyogkush/jquery.textAutoSize - hasn't been updated in a while but worked well enough back when I wrote it.

Comment: I'll check it and give you feedback, thanks :)

Comment: actually looking at the code it doesn't do it on resize, but could easily be forked and updated to work like that.

Comment: what about `css`-solution for this question?  https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: @Igor I added a font-size : 10vw on my css but it didn't worked, I think I don't really understand how to use this css solution !
I'm working on the Derek's solution to make his script working as I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally discovered a jquery script which can do it easily, without needs to modify the code.

The jquery script is FitText (http://fittextjs.com/).

Thanks to Igor Ivancha, I found this script at the bottom of the css solution your purposed :p

You just need to add :

```
$(titre)
.fitText(1.5);
$(para)
.fitText(0.4);
```

into the `<script>` tag then it will work properly. Thanks all !